# Database design suggestions

Tags: database-design, yii

After researching online, I have come up with the following database tables.  Here are some information to assist with my approach.  I will be using Yii Framework for development.

1. Each vehicle has many service types.
2. Each vehicle will have it's own set of check-list questions, to be answered after each service.
3. There's a primary check-list table, with all possible questions.

I was wondering if there was a better solution, or additional modifications to be made before I start developing.  Also, if you have done something similar, I would really appreciate your input.

```
TABLE vehicle
  id
  make_id

TABLE service
  id
  vehicle_id
  schedule_date

TABLE checklist
  id
  question (text)
  type_id  (some are check-boxes, some are drop-downs)

TABLE checklist_set (user who requests the service, must also select related checks from check-list)
  id
  vehicle_id
  checklist_question_id

TABLE checklist_response (table to hold all answers)
  id
  service_id
  checklist_question_id
  answer (selected value from checklist/type_id)
  notes (additional findings)
```

With this approach, a new question could be added to the check-list, and user will have it available for selection if they're booking their vehicle in for servicing.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you need a code-review (design review) rather than help with specific problem.

Comment: Evidently, I haven't built a system like this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to replace

```
checklist_set
    id
    vehicle_id
    checklist_question_id
```

with

```
checklist_set
    id
    service_id
    checklist_question_id
```

because service also contains vehicles on 1x1 relationship and encapsulates better the business logic.

Also, you can change:

```
checklist_response
    id
    service_id
    checklist_question_id
    answer
    notes
```

to

```
checklist_response
    id
    checklist_set_id
    answer
    notes
```

because now using checklist_set_id you can have the correlated service.

With some additional refinements i think you can try the following schema:

```
vehicle
    id
    make_id

service
    id
    vehicle_id
    schedule_date

checklist
    id
    type_id
    question

service_checklist
    id
    service_id
    checklist_id

checklist_response
    id
    service_checklist_id
    answer
    notes
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. :-)